# How do I slant adjoining edges?

Tags: modeling, mesh

If I have a cylinder that is 1 inch tall, how can I slope the top from the front to the back down to, say, a quarter inch evenly? If I select all the edges or all the vertices, they just move down together. Not sure if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Shear the top of the cylinder by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Y</kbd> to shear Vertically or <kbd>X</kbd> Horizontally and adjust the amount of Shearing with the mouse or input a value, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply.

Note that the mesh is Sheared relative to the view angle.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!