# Rotate end face of Cylinder keeping cylinder diameter

Tags: modeling, transforms, faces

I once saw a tutorial on YouTube that gave me a simple keystroke to rotate the end face of a cylinder without deforming the sides. I used it many times, but then didn't require it for a year, until now, when it would be really useful.

Most answers in public forums relate to using the bisect tool instead of rotate, but that was not the solution I came across on YouTube and interrupts workflow.

Does anybody know how to do this? It is extremely useful and precise, as you can simply enter [something] then [r] and then the degree, and it forms a perfect turn in the cylinder without crushing the sides.

Comment: You Rock! Thank you, moonboots! Not sure how to enter the degree, but it works for me.

Comment: actually it's not in degree, it's an Offset value as you can see in the Operator box, you move your vertices on the chosen axis

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33497 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116183

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the **Shear** tool, shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (mh yes, you'd better not have lost a finger), it will make the selection slide on the X or Y (it's *View* orientation by default), then press 1 or -1 to get a 45° or -45° angle (the value is an *Offset*, not an angle, as you are not doing a rotation, you are sliding the vertices on an axis). Open the *Operator* box to enter or modify the values manually:

[image]

[image]

Comment: As I said, this is great, and a great solution, but I'm still not sure it's the solution I once found on YouTube. But either way, I really appreciate the help. Bisect was killing me.

Comment: it was the Knife tool maybe? Once you've pressed K you press C to cut orthogonally or 45°, and press Z to cut through

Comment: I just don't know. I feel like a complete moron. I never write down these useful things, and then months later, I'm like, "wait, how did I do that again?!"